# Accessing derived class' member functions in base template function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a class called `DBDriver` that handles communication with a given table in a database. Its public entry point is a function template called `execute_query()`, which executes SELECT queries. Upon calling this function, some database logic is performed, and then a provided container (of the template type) is populated with results. This looks something like the following:

```
class DBDriver {

    ...

    template <typename CONT_T>
    void execute_query(const std::string& query, CONT_T& container);

    ...

};

template <typename CONT_T>
void DBDriver::execute_query(const std::string& query, CONT_T& container) {
    DBCursor& cursor = ...  // some database logic here
    populate_container(container, cursor);
}
```

Of course, the above will not compile, as `populate_container()` is not defined in `DBDriver`.

`DBDriver` should be purely virtual and have several classes derive from it (one for each database table involved). Each derived class will define its own overloads of `populate_container()`, one for each relevant container type. This will look something like the following:

```
class SampleTableDBDriver : public DBDriver {

    // ...

    populate_container(const ContainerTypeOne& container, DBCursor& cursor);
    populate_container(const ContainerTypeTwo& container, DBCursor& cursor);

    // ...

};
```

My original attempt at this was unsuccessful, as I would have needed to define a virtual function template in `DBDriver` to serve as an entry point to a derived class' `populate_container()` overloads. (Of course such a thing does not exist in C++, hence my issue.)

Is there a cleaner, idiomatic solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `execute_query` is a template function is you need a generic container. What if you define a `Interface` for the container?

```
class IContainer
{};
```

Template Functions cannot be virtual. Therefore, you can use the [Template Method Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/cpp/1).

```
class DBDriver 
{
    public:
    void execute_query(const std::string& query, IContainer **_ppContainer);
    {
        DBCursor& cursor = ...  // some database logic here
        populate_container(_ppContainer, cursor);
    }

    virtual void populate_container(IContainer **_ppContainer, DBCursor &_dbCursor) = 0;
};
```

And let every derived class implement `populate_container` and also provide their custom `Container`.

```
class SampleTableDBDriver : public DBDriver 
{
    public:
        class ContainerTypeOne : public IContainer
        {};

        void populate_container(IContainer **_ppContainer, DBCursor &_dbCursor) 
        {
              ContainerTypeOne *pContainer = new ContainerTypeOne();
              //....
              (*_ppContainer) = pContainer;
        }
};


SampleTableDBDriver  oSampleDriver;
IContainer *pContainer = NULL;
std::string szQuery = // some query ;
oSampleDriver.execute_query(szQuery, &pContainer);
if(pContainer != NULL)
{
    SampleTableDBDriver::ContainerTypeOne  *pSampleDriverContainer = 
        dynamic_cast<SampleTableDBDriver::ContainerTypeOne*>(pContainer); 

    //use pSampleDriverContainer 
}
```

**Edit:** For supporting multiple containers.

In your original design the `populate_container` seems to be overloaded in derived classes. In that case you would still pass the **exact** container from outside while calling `execute_query`.
Same thing can be done with this `Template Method` design. Then, you will need to decipher the type of container inside the `populate_container` function as follows:

New signature : `int populate_container(IContainer *_pContainer, DBCursor &_dbCursor)`

```
int populate_container(IContainer *_pContainer, DBCursor &_dbCursor) 
{
      if(dynamic_cast<ContainerTypeOne *>(_pContainer) != NULL)
      {
          ContainerTypeOne *pContainerOne = _pContainer;
          //populate the result by using pContainerOne
          return 1;   
      }

      if(dynamic_cast<ContainerTypeTwo *>(_pContainer) != NULL)
      {
          ContainerTypeOne *pContainerTwo = _pContainer;
          //populate the result by using pContainerTwo
          return 1;   
      }

      //no, I do not support the container you passed.
      return 0;
}

SampleTableDBDriver  oSampleDriver;
SampleTableDBDriver::ContainerTypeOne oSampleContainerTypeOne;
std::string szQuery = // some query ;
if(oSampleDriver.execute_query(szQuery, &oSampleContainerTypeOne) != 0)
{
    //use oSampleContainerTypeOne;
}
```

Comment: The problem I see with this is that a derived instance must be able to support multiple types of containers. For example, `SampleTableDBDriver` might be responsible for supporting both `ContainerTypeOne` and `ContainerTypeTwo`. How could this be modified to allow for that?

Comment: You cannot have derived classes provide their own containers. This makes little sense. The caller passes a container it needs to populate.

Comment: @n.m : What if the driver does not support the container received as parameter?

Comment: @sameerkn that's the problem you are supposed to solve.

Comment: @n.m. Also the reason the populate_container is implemented by every derived class is that the derived class knows only about their own containers. Else every driver needs to know about every container. OP can please clear this doubt.

Comment: "the reason the populate_container is implemented by every derived class is that the derived class knows only about their own containers" I gather the reason is that the derived class knows about its *database table*, not about its containers. The reason OP wanted a template is that he wanted the base class and *any* derived class support *any* container. The problem only arises because *any* appears twice in the previous sentence. If each derived class has its own container, why pass a container to the base class function?

Comment: @n.m. : Okay in that case you are making container something standard which every driver needs to know. In that case there has to be a container  interface `IContainer` which can be used by every driver in a generic way to populate any kind of container which implements the interface. This can be easily done inside `populate_container` if `populate_container` receives an interface `IContainer *pc` and call all the interface funcitons on `pc` i.e `pc->FillData()` etc.  `FillData()` is member_function of `IContainer`.

Comment: Yes this is essentially what I have proposed in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have options to choose from:

1. If you don't need populate_container() to be a member of DBDriver and can extend (or define) container interface, just implement

   ```
   ContainerTypeOne::populate(DBCursor& cursor);
   ```
2. Make populate_container() a friend (in case you need access to private members of DBDriver):

   ```
   template <typename CONT_T> friend void execute_query(const std::string& query, CONT_T& container);
   ```
3. Make populate_container() a non-member template function (if you don't need access to private members of DBDriver)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to employ the separation of concerns principle.

Querying databases goes to its own class hierarchy, and populating container goes to its own separate class hierarchy. These two hierarchies know nothing about each other, e.g. DBDriverThirteen knows nothing about ContainerFortyTwo. The two hierarchies only touch at their roots, i.e. DBDriver (and so its every derived class) knows about IContainerPopulator but nothing about any specific containers.

You may have a template that builds a specific ContainerPopulator for each container type. Assume for simplicity that you only need to support standard containers of strings that implement `push_back`.

```
struct IContainerPopulator {
    virtual void push_back(const std::string&) = 0;
};

template <class CONT_T>
struct ContainerPopulator : IContainerPopulator {
    StandardContainerPopulator (CONT_T& cont) : cont(cont) {}
    void push_back(const std::string& s) override { cont.push_back(s); }
  private:
    CONT_T& cont;
};
```

Now you can do this

```
template <typename CONT_T>
void execute_query(const std::string& query, CONT_T& container) {
   execute_query_adapted(query, ContainerPopulator<CONT_T>(container));
}

// no template!
virtual void execute_query_adapted(const std::string&,
                                   IContainerPopulator&&) = 0;
```

By now you have probably recognised that `IContainerPopulator` is nothing but a specialised poor man's function binder. Why write another one if we have pretty good support in the language and its standard library? If you only need to support `push_back`, you can alternatively do this:

```
template <typename CONT_T>
void execute_query(const std::string& query, CONT_T& container) {
   execute_query_adapted2(query, 
                          [&](const std::string& s){container.push_back(s);});
}

// no template
virtual void execute_query_adapted2(const std::string&,
                                    std::function<void(const std::string&)>) = 0;
```

Now if you need more than just `push_back` (or any fixed set of functions)  and/or more than `std::string` (or any fixed set of types), things can get really hairy. More information would be needed about potential implementations of `populate_query`.

Comment: If you add more information I will try to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't mind using [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) (or [Boost.TypeIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html), which doesn't require RTTI), you can use [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) and `void*` to get what you want. It's a bit dirty, but it does the job.

```
#include <functional>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>

class driver {
public:
    template <typename Container, typename Populator>
    void register_populator(Populator populator) {
        populators[type_index<Container>()] = [populator](void* v) {
            Container& container = *static_cast<Container*>(v);
            populator(container);
        };
    }

    template <typename Container>
    void execute(Container& container) {
        auto it = populators.find(type_index<Container>());
        if (it != populators.end()) {
            it->second(&container);
        }
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    static std::type_index type_index() {
        return std::type_index(typeid(std::remove_cv_t<T>));
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void (void*)>> populators;
};
```

Then use like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    driver d;

    d.register_populator<std::vector<int>>([](std::vector<int>&) {
        std::cout << "Populate vector<int>\n";
    });

    d.register_populator<std::vector<float>>([](std::vector<float>&) {
        std::cout << "Populate vector<float>\n";
    });

    std::vector<int> int_vector;
    std::vector<float> float_vector;

    d.execute(int_vector);
    d.execute(float_vector);
}
```

Output:

```
Populate vector<int>
Populate vector<float>
```